# error while working with boost::sregex_token_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-regex

I want to search for a regular expression and print it with a color. I used boost::sregex_token_iterator to do this. this is my code

```
    boost::regex re("ab.");
    string s="";
    string buf;
    string infile("retest.txt");
    //string color="green";
    ifstream in(infile.c_str());
    int lcount=0;
    while (getline(in,buf))
    {
       boost::sregex_token_iterator p(buf.begin(), buf.end(), re, 0);
       boost::sregex_token_iterator end;
       lcount++;
       cout <<"line : "<<lcount<<endl;
       for (;p != end;++p)
       {
           string m(p->first, p->second);
           cout<< m <<endl;
           //cout <<*(p->first)<<endl;
           //cout <<*(p->second)<<endl;
           //unsigned int pos = buf.find(m);
           buf = buf.insert(p->first,"\e[0;32m");
           buf = buf.insert(p->second+m.length()+7,"\e[0m");
       }
       cout<<"\n";
       s.append(buf);
       s.append("\n");
     }
   in.close();
   cout <<"s is:  "<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

but I get this error :

> In file included from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:35:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/regex/config.hpp:53,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:28,
>                    from main3.cc:3:
>   /usr/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:92:7: warning: #warning "Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results" [-Wcpp]
>   main3.cc: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
>   main3.cc:36:40: error: no matching function for call to âstd::basic_string::insert(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&, const char [8])â
>   main3.cc:36:40: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1182:7: note: void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1182:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1199:9: note: template void std::basic_string::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1199:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   main3.cc:36:40: note:   cannot convert âp.boost::regex_token_iterator::operator-><__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, char, boost::regex_traits, std::allocator >()->boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::.std::pair<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::firstâ (type âconst __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â) to type âstd::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}â
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1230:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1230:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::size_type {aka unsigned int}â
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1252:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1252:7: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:55:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1293:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1293:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::size_type {aka unsigned int}â
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1316:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1316:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1334:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1334:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}â
>   main3.cc:37:51: error: no matching function for call to âstd::basic_string::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, const char [5])â
>   main3.cc:37:51: note: candidates are:
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1182:7: note: void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1182:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1199:9: note: template void std::basic_string::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1199:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   main3.cc:37:51: note:   cannot convert âp.boost::regex_token_iterator::operator-><__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, char, boost::regex_traits, std::allocator >()->boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::.std::pair<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >::second.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator+ >((* &((__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >::difference_type)m.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, *Alloc>::length, std::allocator >()))).*_gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator+ >((* &7))â (type â__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â) to type âstd::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}â
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1230:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1230:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from â__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::size_type {aka unsigned int}â
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1252:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1252:7: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:55:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.tcc:361:6: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/string:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/ios_base.h:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ios:43,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ostream:40,
>                    from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/iostream:40,
>                    from main3.cc:1:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1293:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1293:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from â__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::size_type {aka unsigned int}â
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1316:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1316:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1334:7: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::insert(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator, _CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::pointer = char*]
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/basic_string.h:1334:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from â__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >â to âstd::basic_string::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}â

I know that the type of `p->first` is not the one which insert function accepts. but I don't know how to convert these to each other.

Comment: Point of style, always use preincrement (++lcount) unless you have a reason to use postincrement.

Comment: Have you snipped the error message?

Comment: @alex thanks for the tip . I'm new in c++ . what exactly "snip the error" means ?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the entire error? It seems to be missing a bit.

Comment: oh yes . I snipped the error output . It's too long and I think the part that I've mentioned is the most important one. I got errors like this and each time I would came up with a solution but this time is a little bit different :)

Comment: Nope, you snipped the important part! Copy and paste the error in full.

Comment: @alex I edited my question to show full error output. as you can see the error is too long and boring, but sadly for me as a non-professional programmer they are all look the same !!

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be your usage of [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert). I can't see an insert(iterator, string) version among it's numerous overloads.

You might want to call desired version by explicitly stating length of char array:

```
void insert (iterator p, size_t n, char c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that boost is configured for use with a different version of the compiler rather than the one you are currently using.

Could you add the details of how you compiled it as well?

Comment: you're right there was a misconfiguration in my boost and I could fix it through my boss !!

Comment: Issue with compiler version produces only warning so it is probably not the cause.